# Implementing long press gesture from object library no response- swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uigesturerecognizer, ibaction

I have a google maps in which I want it to recognise long press gestures on markers. For the mean time I just want to map to respond to a long press gesture. I think I have followed the steps to implementing it correctly but don't seem to be getting a response from the long press and not sure why- could it be because I am testing on simulator that it doesn't recognise click as long press? Anyway here is the method I used below so if anybody can see if there is anything I've missed, please let me know.

1.) dragged long tap gesture recogniser from object library into my maps view in the main storyboard.

2.) this put the gestureRecognizers --> map View into my referencing outlet connection

3.) set the min duration to 0.5sec and enabled both touch and tap recognizers to 1.

4.) in the viewcontroller which contains my mapView typed in:

```
     @IBAction func handleLongtap(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("PRESSED")
}
```

5.) then back on the main storyboard did control drag Long Press Gesture recognizer to the view controller and selected "handleLongtap:" which put 'handleLongTap --> longPressGesture" into my view controller 'received actions'

Despite there being no error- i do not get "PRESSED" in my terminal when i do a long click on simulator. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding the gesture recognizer in code:

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
longPress.addTarget(self, action: ViewController.handleTap)
yourPin.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

func handleTap() {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

And just tweak it as you need.

Comment: i did actually do that initially putting the first part in the viewDidLoad and then having the function but it also was not successful since nothing happened and Im not sure why since once again there was no errors.

Comment: I am just trying again exactly the code above just incase to check again (but instead of yourPin I'm putting mapView so anywhere on the map respondes) but am getting the error ViewController has no instance member 'handleTap'- how would I define it?

Comment: Change ViewController in ViewController.handleTap with the name of your View Controller.

Comment: yes that is what I did. my viewController is called FirstViewController so I have longPress.addTarget(self, action: FirstViewController.handleTap) inside the viewdidload below the let longPress= UILongPressGestureRecognizer() and outside of the ViewDidLoad I have func handleTap() { ....} ... still the same error of no instance member. Should I be defining the handleTap elsewhere as well?

Comment: by the way just for reference, here is what I tried before which is what didn't produce a response which is kind of same as you're suggesting. I did: let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "Long"),  mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture) and func Long() { print("PRESSED") }. this did not produce errors but did not print in terminal either.